# Extracting single value from XML array

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have the following XML:

```
<computer>
<extension_attributes>
    <extension_attribute>
      <id>22</id>
      <name>aname</name>
      <type>String</type>
      <multi_value>false</multi_value>
      <value>auidhg</value>
    </extension_attribute>
    <extension_attribute>
      <id>23</id>
      <name>ap</name>
      <type>String</type>
      <multi_value>false</multi_value>
      <value>d3HtVD</value>
    </extension_attribute>
</extension_attributes>
</computer>
```

I want to extract the value for the extension attribute item with the name "aname" (i.e. I want the value `auidhg`). I'm wondering if there is an Xpath statement I can use with `xmllint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy using a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) to select the right `extension_attribute`.

This XPath:

```
//extension_attribute[name='aname']/value
```

returns:

```
<value>auidhg</value>
```

If you just want the text value, you can select the text node...

```
//extension_attribute[name='aname']/value/text()
```

or use [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string) or [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-normalize-space)...

```
normalize-space(//extension_attribute[name='aname']/value)
```

any of these return:

```
auidhg
```

See my links above for more details on the string() and normalize-space() functions and when they might be preferable to just selecting text().